# Create modelform from multiple models to add to database?

Tags: python, django, forms, django-models

In my `postgressql` database I have tables:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    Definition = models.TextField(default='Definition')
    Name = models.TextField(default='Name')

    def __str__(self):
       return self.Name

class Question(models.Model):
    Statement = models.TextField(default='Question')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Statement

class Planit_location(models.Model):
    Planit_location = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='Planit_location')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Planit_location

class ClientDetail(models.Model):
    Sector = models.ForeignKey(Sector, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Client_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='Client_name')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Client_name

class Response(models.Model):
    Question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Response = models.TextField(default='Response')
    Client = models.ForeignKey(ClientDetail, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Planit_Location = models.ForeignKey(Planit_location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Image = models.ForeignKey(Image, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Response
```

I want to create a `modelform` using all these tables so I can add new questions and responses to my database, which are then linked to a topic, location and client (these 3 will be a `dropdownlist` from data in `db`).

I have managed to create a `modelform` for just question and response but when I try to submit it I get `"null value in column "Question_id" violates not-null constraint"`

Here is the code:

```
 if request.method == 'POST':
    qform = QuestionForm(request.POST)
    rform = ResponseForm(request.POST)
    if qform.is_valid() and rform.is_valid():
        qf = qform.save()
        rf = rform.save()
        return render(request, 'app/adddatatest.html', {
           "qform": QuestionForm(),
           "rform": ResponseForm(),
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking for is_valid() in view do this:

```
qf = qform.save() # Goes to database
rf = rform.save(commit=False) # Doesn't goes to database
rf.Question = qf # gets required attribute
rf.save() # then goes to database
```

You can't save Response object without specifying the the foreign key Question. So  in `rform.save` pass argument `commit=False` to not actually saving it in database yet. Then add the value for the foreign key to the new created Response object, foreign key is required otherwise you will get `IntegrityError`. Then finally save it to the database.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you very much

Comment: Happy to help :). It would be great if you will accept the answer if it solves your problem, if you face any other problems, let me know.

Comment: I now want to add Topic into the mix as a dropdownlist which i have done so. It manages to save and add to the db but for Topic, it is creating a new topic instead of using existing data. e.g. i want to link Topic id 44 to a new response but it creates a new id 60 and links that instead @VaibhavVishal

Comment: `my_topic = Topic.objects.get(pk=44)` `rf.Topic = my_topic` `rf.save()`, you need to do something like this. If you can't figure it out, add the code you are trying for topic, then I can tell where you are doing something wrong

Comment: I have the Topic as a dropdownlist, so how do i get the ID of the topic i choose? In my forms.py this is what it looks like: "class TopicForm(forms.ModelForm):
    topic = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Topic.objects.only('Name').order_by('Name'))". @VaibhavVishal

Comment: Check request.POST['topic'], in your html see if the topics have correct value attribute. The value attribute should have the id of the topic. Also I guess by dropdown list you mean select, eg.- <select name=topic><option value=44>my_topic</option></select>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180513/discussion-between-vaibhav-vishal-and-lloyd).